# How can I set ReadThrough and WriteThrough to CacheConfiguration via a thin client, and then create a Cache?(.net)

Tags: .net, ignite

I have some special configurations, such as ReadThrough and WriteThrough that need to be set to CacheConfiguration, and then create multiple caches (with different names). I don't want to restart the Ignite service, and it seems that I can't do this through the thin client. How can I achieve this? (.net)

By some means, it is possible to dynamically set some properties, such as ReadThrough and WriteThrough, and dynamically initialize caches with different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create caches dynamically from thin client with [IIgniteClient.CreateCache](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/configuration-overview#cache-templates). However, [CacheClientConfiguration](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/dotnetdoc/api/Apache.Ignite.Core.Client.Services.IServicesClient.html) does not provide a way to configure cache store and related properties (`ReadThrough`, `WriteThrough`), because code deployment is not allowed from the client.

There are two ways around that.

## [Cache Templates](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/configuration-overview#cache-templates)

Define a [cache template](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/configuration-overview#cache-templates) (cache configuration with `*` in the name, e.g. `my-store-cache-*`) in the server node configuration and set all store-related properties there.

Then create caches from the thin client using `client.CreateCache<K, V>("my-store-cache-123")`.

## [Compute](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/dotnetdoc/api/Apache.Ignite.Core.Client.Compute.IComputeClient.html) and [Services](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/dotnetdoc/api/Apache.Ignite.Core.Client.Services.IServicesClient.html)

Wrap cache creation logic in a compute job or a service, then call it from the thin client.

Comment: Thanks,my bro. You give me a lot of help.